# Getting non--void error on function return

Tags: swift

I'm getting this error and I know this problem has been addressed on here before by people not adding the return -> to the function. I do not understand why this is still giving me error.

Unexpected non-void return value in void function

I'm trying to return a String called message.

```
     func ParseIt(proURL: String, startStr: String, stopStr: String) -> String {

        let url = URL(string: "https://www.siteimfetchingfrom.com/827444000973")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            } else {
                let htmlContent = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                //print(htmlContent)
                // Get all Product Info
                //var proName = "id=\"productName\" value=\""

                if let contentArray = htmlContent?.components(separatedBy: startStr) {
                    //print(contentArray)
                    if contentArray.count > 0 {
                        //proName = "\" required"

                        let newContentArray = contentArray[1].components(separatedBy: stopStr)

                        if newContentArray.count > 0 {

                            let message = newContentArray[0]

                            //print(newContentArray)
                            print(newContentArray[0])

 return message // Error happens Here
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully where your return statement belongs.  It's not returning from `ParseInt`, it's actually returning from the completion closure passed to `URLSession.shared.dataTask`.  The return type of that completion handler is `void`.

> func dataTask(with request: URLRequest,  completionHandler: @escaping
>   (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask

Answer (score 3):

The line `return message` is written inside of a closure. A return statement written inside a closure will return from the closure, not the surrounding function.

Seeing how you are performing a web request and getting the response, you should have a completion handler instead of a `return`. You can't immediately return a string from `ParseIt` because the request will take time.

```
 // notice the extra completion parameter and the removal of the return type
 func ParseIt(proURL: String, startStr: String, stopStr: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.siteimfetchingfrom.com/827444000973")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        ...

        // replace the return statement with this:
        completion(message)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
ParseIt(proURL: ..., startStr: ..., stopStr: ...) {
    result in

    // do something with "result"
}
```